# Integrating a tensor over a unit sphere

Tags: tensors

We define a second order symmetric tensor $T_{ij}$ as follows:

$$ T_{ij} = \delta_{ij} - 3x_i x_j $$

I need to evaluate

$$ \int_{U} T_{ik} T_{kj} dS$$

Where $U$ is the surface of the unit sphere.

Now  $$T_{ik} T_{kj} = (\delta_{ik} - 3x_i x_k)(\delta_{kj} - 3x_k x_j) = \delta_{ik} \delta_{kj} - 3 x_k x_j \delta_{ik} - 3 x_i x_k \delta_{kj} + 9x_i x_j x_k ^ 2 = \delta_{ij} - 6x_i x_j + 9 x_i x_j x_k ^2 $$

Integrating this term by term, we have

$$\int_{U} \delta_{ij} dS = 4 \pi \delta_{ij}$$

If $i \neq j$

$$ \int_U x_i x_j dS = 0$$

And if i = j,

$$ \int_{U} x_i ^ 2dS = \frac{1}{3}\int_{U} x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 dS = \frac{1}{3}\int_{U} 1 dS = \frac{4\pi}{3}$$

Thus

$$ \int_U x_i x_j dS = \frac{4\pi}{3} \delta_{ij}$$

How do I use symmetry considerations to evaluate $\int_{U} x_i x_j x_k^2 dS$?

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $j$ and $k$ you integrate the odd function $x_i$ over a symmetric set. Therefore $\int_U x_i x_j x_k^2 \, dS = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. But what of the cases in which $i = j = k$, $i = j \neq k$, and $ i = k \neq j$. Is there a shortcut way to evaluate or must we brute force it?

Comment: If $i = j = k$ then we have a quadric, $x_i^4$. If $i = j \neq k$ then we have two squares, $x_i^2 x_k^2$. If $i = k \neq j$ then we have two factors of odd degree, $x_i^3 x_j$, both of which give $0$ when integrated.